# Acquire Token by service account with MSAL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-msal, azure-adal-deprecation

we are using ADAL to acquire tokens by a service account silently (no prompt, no redirect). This is our sample code:

```cs
var clientId = "";
var tenantDomain = "";
var userName = "";
var password = "";
var context = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantDomain));
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, credential);
```

How can I acquire tokens using MSAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this type of authentication in a long time since this is no longer encouraged to be used.

you would also need to set your app reg like this and seems like this option is gone:
[image]

code sample

```
try
            {
                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "yourpassword")        // you should fetch the password
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

                result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes,"username@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com", securePassword).ExecuteAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // See details below
            }
```

You may want to replace it with an SPN secret auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token

Answer (score 1):

Use **AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword()**, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.acquiretokenbyusernamepassword?view=azure-dotnet).

Note that usage of this flow is [discouraged](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication)  as it requires you to handle passwords in your code.